# Absolute rounding error and subnormal numbers

Tags: rounding, ieee-754, ieee

is there an x in subnormal numbers in IEEE Single format such that:

|round()−|/||>/2.

if there is not please explain.

Note: round's mode is to the nearest

= machine epsilon = in this case 2^-23

Comment: If *x* is a subnormal number in IEEE-754 binary32 (“single”) and the round function rounds to the nearest IEEE-754 binary32, then round(*x*) = *x*. Do you mean to ask whether there is a real number *x* in the range of IEEE-754 binary32 subnormal values with that property, that is, an *x* in 0 < *x* < 2^-126? If so, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Let *x* be 2<sup>−1000</sup>. The two IEEE-754 binary32 (“single precision” floating-point) values nearest *x* are 0 and 2<sup>−149</sup>. So round(*x*) is 0, so |round(*x*)−*x*| / |x| = |0−2<sup>−1000</sup>| / |2<sup>−1000</sup>| = 1, which is greater than 2<sup>−23</sup>.

For another example, let *x* be 2<sup>−149</sup>+2<sup>−150</sup> = 1½•2<sup>−149</sup>. The two binary32 values nearest it are 2<sup>−149</sup> and 2<sup>−148</sup> (which equal 1•2<sup>−149</sup> and 2•2<sup>−149</sup>). These are equidistant from *x*, and the rule for breaking ties is to choose the number with the even low bit, which is 2<sup>−148</sup>. Then |round(*x*)−*x*| / |x| = |2<sup>−148</sup> − (2<sup>−149</sup>+2<sup>−150</sup>)| / |2<sup>−149</sup>+2<sup>−150</sup>| = |2•2<sup>−149</sup> − 1½•2<sup>−149</sup>| / |1½•2<sup>−149</sup>| = |2−1½| / |1½| = ½ / 1½ = ⅓, which is greater than 2<sup>−23</sup>.